# How to move disk space from one lvm to another?

Tags: centos, lvm

I have disk space allocated in one of my machine in below way.As you can see , it has two disks : sda and sdb

Root LVM - vg01-lv_root - has 445.6G size ( sda )

Home LVM - vg02-lv_home - has 893.7G size (sdb)

I want to cut off : 400GB from Root LVM and add it to Home LVM

Can someone please let me know if its possible and how to achieve this?

**At Present**

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 893.8G  0 disk
├─sda1                    8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                    8:2    0 893.3G  0 part
  ├─vg01-lv_swap (dm-0) 253:0    0  89.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─vg01-lv_root (dm-1) 253:1    0 445.6G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg01-lv_var (dm-3)  253:3    0 178.9G  0 lvm  /var
  └─vg01-lv_usr (dm-4)  253:4    0 178.9G  0 lvm  /usr
sdb                       8:16   0 893.8G  0 disk
└─sdb1                    8:17   0 893.8G  0 part
  └─vg02-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0 893.7G  0 lvm  /home
```

**Desired**

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 893.8G  0 disk
├─sda1                    8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                    8:2    0 893.3G  0 part
  ├─vg01-lv_swap (dm-0) 253:0    0  89.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─vg01-lv_root (dm-1) 253:1    0  45.6G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg01-lv_var (dm-3)  253:3    0 178.9G  0 lvm  /var
  └─vg01-lv_usr (dm-4)  253:4    0 178.9G  0 lvm  /usr
sdb                       8:16   0 893.8G  0 disk
└─sdb1                    8:17   0 893.8G  0 part
  └─vg02-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0 1293.7G  0 lvm  /home
```

Thanks,

Manoj Kumar

Answer (score 1):

short answer: **you can't**

long answer:

data to be freed is inside another disk on another vg.

you would theorically have to:

1. shrink filesystem `/` this is done by umounting / (booting on a live disk, use `fsck` , `resize2fs` ) this is the hardest part.
2. shrink logical volume ( `lvredure --size -400G  lv_root` ), you now have 400 Gb free on `vg01` (more likely free space is between `lv_root` and `lv_var` )
3. move vg01's data to bottom of sda2 (`pvmove --alloc x lv_var` and `pvmove --alloc x lv_usr` ), you'll have to find x. I am not sure this can be done.
4. use `pvresize` to free 400 Gb
5. break partitionning of sda to recreate `sda2` and create a `sda3` with 400 Gb freed above (`fdisk` )

Now, things come easy

6. create a new physical disk (`pvcreate /dev/sda3` )
7. extend vg02 ( `vgextend vg02 /dev/sda3` )
8. extend lv_home ( `lvextend +400 Gb lv_home` )
9. resize /home ( `resize2fs /home` )

Do not follow thoses steps if you don't understand them.

Step 1. 2. and 3. are very likely to break system.

Step 4. and 5. are risky but doable.

---

It would be more easy to have a planned rebuild system (rather than emergency have breaking `/` )

Comment: Absolutely. The primary mistake was over-allocating space to LVs and their associated filesystems in the first place.